# Class Just For Semantics

Tags: java, c++, oop, class-design

I am building an application that allows you to apply styles to regular expressions and their capture groups. I have a class called `RegexGroup` which contains a list of `RegexGroup`'s and `Regex`'s.

I will make a gui front-end in order to utilize these classes and I started by making a Project class that will be serializable but I realized that a `Project` class would be exactly the same as the `RegexGroup`. Is it good or bad practice to create a `Project` class that is exactly the same as another just because they will be used in different contexts? Or should I just stick with using the `RegexGroup` class?
Thanks in advance, ell.

note: I had trouble thinking of a title, please correct me if the use of the word "semantics" is incorrect

note: I am currently writing this in java but would this be an appropriate use of `typedef` in c++?

Edit: The classes are literally exactly the same. Their implementation and interface is completely identical, there are no differences whatsoever.

Comment: Refactor it so that the implementation is in a separate class, and then you can use the implementation in various outward-facing classes that require it.

Comment: Perhaps you should elaborate on "exactly the same".  Do you mean the classes have *exactly* the same methods, or does the `Project` class actually add something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a Project is actually a RegexGroup . Then you could just derive from it.
It makes perfect sense, if you say something is another, then that's where you derive from it.

```
class Project: public RegexGroup { }
```

And of course, along the way you might find subtle differences where you could add stuff to the separate classes, or even create a base class for both.

And yes, in c++ you could just use `typedef` to declare another alias to the same type.

```
typedef RegexGroup Project;
```

Comment: Note that inheritance has the nasty side-effect of allowing you to nest a `Project` instance inside a `RegexGroup` (groups nest).  I really wouldn't recommend this.

Comment: it depends on the implementation and definition. If it's defined well and it is actually a RegexGroup, then the fact that it is allowed in a RegexGroup is fine and logical. If it is not defined well, and it is not in fact a RegexGroup then of course it shouldn't derive from it.

Comment: And it's not a side-effect, it's a logical conclusion, and thus by design.

Comment: I don't take OP's "exactly the same" literally.  They probably meant "lots of common methods".  If they were *exactly* the same, then there would be no point in having a `Project` class in the first place.

Comment: He is comparing his situation to a use of **typedef** so it should be the same.

Answer (score 1):

Whatever helps with readability of code, should help (if it doesn't hurt other important characteristics, like i.e. performance). So creating another class (or, for that reason, aliasing one that exists) is OK.

*I guess* in Java you can subclass your Project from RegexGroup and then leave the body of Project empty.

Yes, in C++ you can use typedef. Or you cannot: implementation depends on whether you want to get a compiler error whenever you try passing RegexGroup to function that expexts Project, or not.

Comment: Note that inheritance has the nasty side-effect of allowing you to nest a `Project` instance inside a `RegexGroup` (groups nest).  I really wouldn't recommend this.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the problem correctly, I think it would be perfectly fine if you subclass the RegexGroup to give the same class another name if this works for you. In the classes definition it would be visible that it's a subclass of RegexGroup, so this wouldn't be information hiding. If you sooner or later realize that there's a little difference, you can even also just add this to the subclass.

Answer (score 0):

If classes are used in different contexts, I would definitely create a separate class.  In particular, I would avoid re-use through inheritance (implementation inheritance) because of the following scenario:

```
class Regex { ... };
class RegexGroup
{
    public void add ( Regex pattern ) { ... }
    public void add ( RegexGroup group ) { ... }
}

class Project extends RegexGroup { ... }

// later on.
Project project = ...;
RegexGroup group = ...;
group.add(project);
```

If that last line does not make sense for your application, then it violates the [Liskov Substitution Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) and inheritance should be avoided.

From my understanding, it seems to me that the natural structure is: "every project has a *root regex group*".  If that is correct, then your project will probably have the following look:

```
class Project
{
    private RegexGroup rootGroup;
    public void add ( Regex pattern )
    {
        this.rootGroup.add(pattern);
    }
    public void add ( RegexGroup group )
    {
        this.rootGroup.add(group);
    }
}
```

This takes a little extra code to forward the calls but probably models the application structure most naturally.